# A2C unable to solve Cartpole

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, implementation, advantage-actor-critic

I have coded my own **A2C** implementation using **PyTorch**. However, despite having followed the algorithm pseudo-code from several sources, my implementation is not able to achieve a proper *Cartpole* control after **2000** episodes.

```
import torch

import numpy as np

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

from collections import deque

device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')


class A2C_agent:
    def __init__(self, observation_space, action_space, batch_size=100, gamma=.99, alpha_actor=1e-3, alpha_critic=1e-3):

        self.observation_space = observation_space
        self.action_space = action_space

        self.alpha_actor = alpha_actor
        self.alpha_critic = alpha_critic

        self.gamma = gamma

        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.experience_batch = deque(maxlen=self.batch_size)

        # Actor network
        self.actor = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.observation_space, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, self.action_space),
            nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        ).to(device)

        # Actor weight initialization
        for layer in self.actor:
            if isinstance(layer, nn.Linear):
                nn.init.xavier_uniform_(layer.weight)

        # Critic network
        self.critic = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.observation_space, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 1)
        ).to(device)

        # Critic weight initialization
        for layer in self.critic:
            if isinstance(layer, nn.Linear):
                nn.init.xavier_uniform_(layer.weight)

        self.optim_actor = optim.Adam(
            self.actor.parameters(), lr=self.alpha_actor)
        self.optim_critic = optim.Adam(
            self.critic.parameters(), lr=self.alpha_critic)

    def pred_action(self, state):
        state_tensor = torch.Tensor(state).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
        action_probs = self.actor(state_tensor).detach()
        action = torch.multinomial(action_probs, 1).item()
        return action

    def save_experience(self, state, action, reward, state_next, done):
        self.experience_batch.append(
            (state, action, reward, state_next, done))

        # Learn when the experience batch is full or when the episode ends
        if len(self.experience_batch) % self.batch_size == 0 or done:
            self.learn()
            # Reset experience
            self.experience_batch.clear()

    def learn(self):
        # Initialize the loss
        actor_loss = 0.
        critic_loss = 0.

        # Loop through the experience batch
        for state, _, reward, state_next, done in self.experience_batch:
            state_tensor = torch.tensor(state).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
            state_next_tensor = torch.tensor(state_next).to(device)

            advantage = reward + (1 - done) * self.gamma * \
                self.critic(state_next_tensor) - \
                self.critic(state_tensor).detach()

            # Compute action prob distribution and sample action
            action_probs = self.actor(state_tensor).detach()
            action_distrib = torch.distributions.Categorical(
                probs=action_probs)
            action = action_distrib.sample().unsqueeze(0)
            action_tensor = torch.tensor(action, dtype=torch.int64)

            # Compute and accumulate loss
            critic_loss += advantage.pow(2)
            actor_loss += -action_distrib.log_prob(action_tensor) * advantage

        # Average the loss
        batch_len = len(self.experience_batch)
        actor_loss /= batch_len
        critic_loss /= batch_len

        # Update Actor and Critic networks
        self.optim_actor.zero_grad()
        actor_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        self.optim_actor.step()

        self.optim_critic.zero_grad()
        critic_loss.backward()
        self.optim_critic.step()
```

Is my A2C agent correctly implemented? Or did I misunderstood any part of the algorithm?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Antonio. From what I recall, MountainCar is a reinforcement learning environment with sparse rewards. Has your agent ever reached the victory state yet (top of the mountain)? If not, there is no reason that it should learn an optimal policy.

Comment: Hi @DeepQZero, and sorry! I had a typo when I wrote the question. I meant the Cartpole environment, not MountainCar. I've just edited the question. Thanks for the comment :-)